# Which child number of the parent element is a child - is this a property?

Tags: javascript, parent-child

Three divs:

> ```
> <div id='container'>
>     <div id='one'>One</div>
>     <div id='two'>Two</div>
>     <div id='three'>Three</div>
> </div>
> ```

When clicked, they report what child number they are in the parent element:

> ```
> function whatAmI(source){
>     //this function tells you which number the child is
>     //in everything nested in the parent element
>     for(x=0;x<source.parentElement.children.length;x++){
>         if(source.parentElement.children[x]==source){
>             return alert("I am child #" + x);
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> container = document.getElementById('container')
> for(x=0;x<container.children.length;x++){
>     container.children[x].addEventListener('click', 
>               function(){
>                   return whatAmI(this)
>               })
> }
> ```

Is this a really roundabout way of doing things? By iterating through the parent. Surely there must be a better property?

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/H9aLf/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're in an environment that supports [`Array.prototype.indexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) (for example, a modern browser, including IE9+, or node.js), you can use this instead of `whatAmI`:

```
container = document.getElementById('container')
for(x=0;x<container.children.length;x++){
    container.children[x].addEventListener('click', function(){
        alert(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(container.children, this))
    });
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nNYUm/

Since it's a generic method, it can operate on a NodeList like `container.children`.

You can also remove the loop that creates a click handler per child div by delegating the clicks to the parent div:

```
container = document.getElementById('container')
container.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    alert(Array.prototype.indexOf.call(container.children, e.target));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/nNYUm/1

Comment: Wow, this is awesome. Especially the second snippet - would never have thought of that!

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables That's extremely useful when you're using ajax to populate a container. For example, if you have a `<ul>` where `<li>` elements are added or removed dynamically, you can add a single click handler to the ul and be done with it; if you don't, you have to attach new event handlers to every list item you add, the moment you add them.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're looking for jQuery's `index` method.

Per their [documentation](http://api.jquery.com/index/), here's a jsfiddle: [working example](http://jsfiddle.net/8HR9B/)

Comment: The question doesn't mention jQuery.

Comment: True, but what's wrong with a working, concise alternative?  My guess, is that because he _IS_ working with markup, he most likely _does_ have jQuery despite not being explicit about it.

Comment: Nope, no jQuery. Javascript, neat :D